# Product attribute genarate value depending on other attribute value

Tags: magento-1.7, product, attributes

Can somebody help me.....is there a way to get value from more then one product attribute's

Example: Let say I have product with attribute color, size and model (red, 8.5, sneaker). Know I need a attribute that generate these value from 3 attribute's and make as the value red8.5sneaker

Instead of creating attribute with a text field or dropdown, I need these value from this other attribute's

Comment: Can you describe your scenario a bit more? What do you need it for?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Your custom attribute just needs its own source model which loads the options from each of the desired attributes and returns those options.